# Json string to Google Calendar Chart

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, json, google-visualization

I have a Json string which I want to show in a Google Calendar Chart. 
This is the Json string I am using as sample data.

```
[
    {
        "Date": "2014-January-15",
        "Frequencies": 11
    },
    {
        "Date": "2014-January-8",
        "Frequencies": 22
    },
]
```

Then I use this method to plot the graph.

```
function drawCalendarChart(jsonObj) {

    var dataValues = eval(jsonObj)
       var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(dataValues);
       data.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Date' });
       data.addColumn({ type: 'number', id: 'Reports' });

       for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {

           var date = new Date(dataValues[i].Date);
           alert("This is the date " + date + "and frequency " + dataValues[i].Frequencies)

           //           data.addRow([new Date(dataValues[i].Date),  dataValues[i].Frequencies]);

       }
       var options = {
         title: "Calendar Chart",
         height: 350
       };
       var chart = new google.visualization.Calendar(document.getElementById('chart'));

       chart.draw(data, options);
       var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table'));
       table.draw(data, { showRowNumber: true });
   }
```

The alert is  giving correct values for the frequencies but Invalid Date for the Dates.
The Calendar Chart is showing only the title since the dates are invalid.
The data table is showing correct values for the frequencies and NaN,NaN for the dates.
[image: Data Table Result]

I tried to format the date in several ways but I cannot get this work. Now I'm more confised since even the alert is not showing at least the data as it is in the file e.g. 2014-January-12.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The strange thing is that the alert which is executed before the chart is populated is giving Invalid Date.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the date should be formatted like this: "yyyy-mm-dd".

Here is what the data should probably look like:

```
[
    {
        "Date": "2014-01-15",
        "Frequencies": 11
    },
    {
        "Date": "2014-01-8",
        "Frequencies": 22
    },
]
```

Comment: Can you give an example please. Since I already tried but cannot get it work. Thanks

Comment: "2014-01-15" or "2014-01-07"

Comment: @user2307236 - I added an example. Have you tried data like in my sample?

Comment: Yes I tried but getting same problem. However month must by word since I do not have control on it.

Comment: @user2307236 - I just noticed that you're adding a column to your dataTable that maps to "Report" in your data. I don't see a "Report" property in your data. Am I missing something or did you just remove it for clarity? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can work, but that's not guarantied by js specification.
Read [mozilla specifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for example.

Anyway, you can try to transform date like this:

```
    function parseDate(input){
    var pattern=/(.*?)\-(.*?)\-(.*?)$/;
    var result = input.replace(pattern,function(match,p1,p2,p3){
        return (p3<10?"0"+p3:p3)+" "+p2.substring(0, 3)+" "+p1;
    });
    return result;
}
```

In your code:

```
var date = new Date(parseDate(dataValues[i].Date));
```